# different king of google font type

Tags: css

I try to add the Montserrat font in the html document on google fonts and if I change the value in hss to h1 with font-family: "Montserrat-Black"; , not working.

In some internet tutorials from 2018 I saw that if you put in the head the link from google font and in css you wrote "Montserrat-black", it is updated. Why is not it working?

To work, I have to select from google font "montserrat black" and in CSS to add only font-families: "Montserrat" and it shows me the black font. But I want to put other headings for example Montserrat-light, Montserrat-Regular but it doesn't work.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOe8U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Head over to https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?sidebar.open&selection.family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,500;1,500;1,700;1,900

and you'll see instructions on how to link the font file and then what to specify in the font-family.

[image: Screenshot]